# Where to find georeferenced VFR Navigation Chart

Tags: geospatial

I am looking for Canada coverage VNC map for my GIS project. I've looked for it, but haven't been able to find anything.  Ideally, a geoTiff or vector would do, or a WMS would be great.

Comment: You might want to expand your question a bit to explain what you would consider a "good result". Are you looking for global data, or just one country/region? Do you need vector data, or are georeferenced raster maps acceptable? For example, ESRI provides [georeferenced FAA charts](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9ff892e372e84a8eb23c866865b2e6cc) for US airspace via a WMS. Will that meet your needs, and if not, why not?

Comment: [VFR Navigation Charts](http://products.navcanada.ca/Products/VFR-Navigation-Charts-VNC "VFR Navigation Chart") are proprietary in Canada, and can be bought from Nav Canada.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this out ? http://www.ivao.ca/charts/vnc

If this is not what you wanted, might be a good idea to call geography department in Canada to see if they have them in geospatial datasets and to see if they have the latest current information.You might want to ask for further query on where to find them.